# How do I make personalized table pagination?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

How do I style mui component like this?

[image]

I guess using `Pagination` component and `Select` could work, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming this is using the MUI-X DataGrid,**

You can override all the components in the footer of the DataGrid, including the Pagination, the Select, and the Typography components.

See this for more info on how to do so: https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/

**Assuming this is using the MUI Table,**

You can override the footer component of the Table and add your own custom stuff, or just customized components from MUI.

See these for more info on how to do so: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/table-pagination/, https://mui.com/material-ui/api/table-footer/